# Выполнение JavaScript в ng-view в определенном порядке

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

В ng-view попадает HTML разметка, которая содержит в себе приблизительно следующий код.

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script>
    window.console.log(window.someObject);
</script>
```

Ожидается, что сначала загрузится и выполнится код, находящийся в файле script1.js. Затем выполнится код во втором теге script и в window.someobject будет лежать объект, инициализированный кодом из файла script1.js.

Но происходит все не так, как ожидается, и в Console выводится undefined. При помощи Developer Tools установил, что script1.js загружается и выполняется корректно. И объект создается в итоге. Сдается мне, что код выполняется асинхронно.

А мне нужно, чтобы Angular выполнил эти скрипты аналогично логике браузера. В строгом порядке, в данном случае синхронно. Как можно такое решить?

Comment: Возможно это поможет https://habrahabr.ru/post/209662/

Comment: Имо подход не совсем правильный. Пробуйте загружать скрипт через [сервис](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) и выводить в консоль из контроллера.